# File format for exporting blender model

Tags: export, blend-files, file-format

Most of the 3D models published online include file formats such as 3ds, max, obj, fbx for download, I wonder if obj and fbx files already allow users of all 3d modelling or animating applications to import them and use? What file format should be available for users to download online? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.fbx and .obj files should be importable for most or any 3d applications.

Comment: +1 for .obj files